# Unable to retrieve logged users info in LDAP php

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I am using LDAP for users login.
Below code is working fine for validating username and password.

```
<?php
$hostname="ldap://mydomain";
$ds=ldap_connect($hostname);
ldap_set_option ($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) or die('Unable to set LDAP opt referrals');
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT, 33);  
if ($ds)
{
$dn="DC=mydomain,DC=mydomain.net";

$username ="username";
$password ="xxxxxxx";
$ldaprdn = 'VCS' . "\\" . $username;

if (!($ldapc=ldap_bind($ds, $ldaprdn, $password))){
echo "<p>Error:" . ldap_error($ds) . "</p>"; 
echo "<p>Error number:" . ldap_errno($ds) . "</p>"; 
echo "<p>Error:" . ldap_err2str(ldap_errno($ds)) . "</p>"; 
die;
}
$filter = "(samaccountname=mani*)";
$attributes =array('mail');//array("name","telephonenumber","mail","samaccountname");

$result = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter,$attributes);
var_dump($result);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $result);
print_r($info);
for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
echo $info[$i]["ou"][0];
}
} else {
echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}

ldap_unbind($ds);
?>
```

But it does not return the logged user info.
The value of **$info["count"]** is always 0.

I think I am misunderstanding the value of base_dn, and filter in ldap_search().

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for my problem.

The filtering is not worked.

So I changed the filter to
    $filter = "(samaccountname=*)";

Now I can retrieve all the records, from the records I can filter more.

Answer (score 0):

To get username and password from user I used this below code. This helped me lots

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="AD Application"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == ""){
        unset($_SESSION);
        unset($_SERVER);
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="AD Application"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Invalid username and password';
    exit;
    }
$logval=explode("\\",$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
$logsize = sizeof($logval);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
if($logsize == 1){
    $loginname=$logval[0];
} else if($logsize == 2) {
    $loginname=$logval[1];
} else {
$loginname = "";
}
}
```